# Find Nearest Element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, point, pixel

How can you finds the elements in a page that are closest to a particular point, based on pixel dimensions??

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go... 
https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-nearest

but you should show what youve done to solve it.